# Running two debug processes in Visual Studio Code (Python, Django, Celery)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to run several debug processes at one click? For example, I would like to run Django development server + Celery daemon in order to be able to debug it at one time. Has anyone tried to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into Multitarget debugging: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging

This allows you to debug multiple processes in VSCode. You can switch back and forth between the currently debugged process using the drop down in the debug widget